# Android: wrong arguments on intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've got problems with using the Intent object of Android.

I'm basically trying to launch another activity:

My Activity, MapActivity, makes use of a MapEventListener, which provides functions to listen to events based on a map which is rendered in the MapActivty Activity. If a marker is pressed on the map, a function of the MapEventListener is Launched.

I  this function I'm trying to implement an Intent object which launches another activty.

This is the function's code:

```
@Override
public void onVectorElementClicked(VectorElement arg0, double arg1,
        double arg2, boolean arg3) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, DetailPerspectiveActivity.class);
    activity.startActivity(intent);


}
```

This is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.hsrw.landschaftsbilder"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/><application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:allowBackup="false">
    <activity android:name=".activities.MapActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.GraphhopperRouteTestActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.DetailPerspectiveActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is about "MapActivity.this" but if I change this to MapActivity.this in the manifest the code is still not compilable. That's what eclipse says about the first argument:

No enclosing instance of the type MapActivity is accessible in scope

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, try to change `Intent intent = new Intent(.activities.MapActivity.this, .activities.DetailPerspectiveActivity.class);` to `Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, DetailPerspectiveActivity.class);` (ie. both MapActivity and DetailPerspectiveActivity).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this already and it didn't workout.

Comment: I moved the MapEventListener class intoh the same package of both activites. The compiler does not complain about the argument DetailPerspectiveActivty.class anymore.

It still complains about the argument MapActivity.this .
MapActiviyt.class does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest.xml file contains problems. you have declared two activities as launcher which will not work

amend manifest.xml code as following.

> Instead of following

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MapActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>            
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activities.GraphhopperRouteTestActivity">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activities.DetailPerspectiveActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

> Use the following code

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MapActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>            
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activities.GraphhopperRouteTestActivity">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activities.DetailPerspectiveActivity">
</activity>
```

**Edit:**
What does this line do in your code.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(.activities.MapActivity.this, .activities.DetailPerspectiveActivity.class);
```

It usually is the following way

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FIRST_ACTIVITY.this, SECOND_ACTIVITY.class);
```

in your case I presume it should be

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, DetailPerspectiveActivity.class);
```

Comment: The problem still remains.

The MapEventListener class, which contains the method to call the DetailPerspectiveActivity is in the same package as the MapActivity.

I tried a static context variable in the MapActivity without any succes as well.

Comment: what exactly is the error? is it running? if yes post the full stack trace. if no then please edit your question with complete code snippet for us to understand..

Comment: I currently use this line of code in the concerning method:

Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, DetailPerspectiveActivity.class);

And this is what eclipse says about MapActivty.this:

No enclosing instance of the type MapActivity is accessible in scope

Comment: not still sure what you are trying to say. The error "No enclosing instance of the type MapActivity is accessible in scope" means MapActivity can not be accessed at this point. now until we see the code how can we figure out why is not accessible. that is why I asked you to add full code snippets.